# How to create name tags with availability zone information in AWS Clouformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a AWS cloudformation to deployment instances and tag the instance based on the Availability zone in which they get deployed. When creating the instances I am using GetAZz and select a availability zone.

```
 AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
```

```
 Value: !Join
          - '-'
          - - 'aws-web'
            - Fn::Select: [ 0, Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region" ]
            - 'network'
```

Output:
Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed.

Expected Output:
aws-web-us-east-1a-network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    Value: !Join
              - '-'
              - - 'aws-web'
                - !Select
                  - 0
                  - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
                - 'network'
```

Comment: Thanks John for your reply, using your response I was able to get the expected output.